# Yii2 add attributes to script tag using registerJs

Tags: yii2, assets, yii2-advanced-app

Is there a way to add attributes to script tag using registerJs?

For example:

```
$this->registerJs("var options ={'a' : 2};", View::POS_END, 'my-options');
```

The above will  output something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var options ={'a' : 2};</script>
```

But I need to add some attributes to script tag(or even change the type for richsnippets)

Comment: not sure this is possible this `registerJs`.. if you place the JS in a separate jsfile you can do this with `registerJsFile` with the `$options` parameter.

Comment: There is a workaround extending base View and overriding registerJs to accept additional parameter(s)...but I made a decision to put it manually with the script tag